# iOS \n is getting removed from my string

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

test has the \n that I want to continue to have in the string, but when I put it into my post variable it gets removed?

```
var test:NSString = myotherstring
var post:NSString = "username=\(MyVariables.username!)&mood=\(test)";
NSLog("PostData: %@",post);
```

[image]

[image]

When I print out post, it removes the \n which I need to have in my string.   I use post for my PHP script and JSON to store this value into my DB.  Right now it stores the value without \n and I want it to store with \n

Comment: It is not removed. You see `vv` on next line.

Comment: yes, but I need it to display \n for my php script.  It is not saving in my db with \n

Comment: are you sure it is not!? show us where you read the data again and where the \n is missing.

Comment: Are you posting this to some server as request URL or where do you save anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\n` in a NSString gets replaced with a `newline character`.  If you want to actually print the character `\` followed by the character `n`, you shoud use "\\n" (the first `\` escapes the second)

Comment: thanks David, this led me on the correct path.  I figured it out and posted an answer but I will mark this as the best answer due to the explanation you provided

Answer (score 0):

`NSLog` will see `\n` as a line break. But the string otherwise is preserved with `\n`. It might be a little confusing but you have to believe that `\n` is there.

Comment: I don't believe the \n is there because it stores it in my DB the same way it shows on the NSLog

Comment: Your DB is likely also displaying the `\n` as a line break. If you're still not convinced, read it back out from the DB and iterate over the characters individually.

Comment: Agreed, that's what I'm thinking too. Have you tried exporting the string to a text file to see if its coming up there? Probably not the best way to check but it's the only one that comes to mind right now

Comment: @Ryan I had to replace \n with \\n.  \n was getting escaped

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
 let newString = test.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: "\\n", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
```